# r shiny - conditionalPanel with condition: check item in list

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have 2 lists each one contains a number of ids `p_id` conditional on another variable `d`.

```
d1 <- as.list(unique(df$p_id[df$d==1]))
d2 <- as.list(unique(df$p_id[df$d==2]))
```

I would like to add a `conditionalPanel` in my shiny app to show/hide a `selectInput`widget accordingly.

In my UI `dashboardPage`, `dashboardBody` I have the following:

```
box(
                  conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "input.p_id.indexOf('d1')!=-1" 
                    , selectInput(
                      inputId = "d_number"
                      ,label = "Select Day:"
                      ,choices = list("Day 1" = "1")
                      ,selected = "1"
                    )
                  ),

                  conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "input.p_id.indexOf('d2')!=-1" 
                    , selectInput(
                      inputId = "d_number"
                      ,label = "Select Day:"
                      ,choices = list("Day 1" = "1", "Day 2" = "2")
                      ,selected = "1"
                      )
                  )          
                ),
```

My understanding is that the `condition` has to be in `js` not `r`. For example, I am trying to replicate `p_id %in% d1`for the first condition. However, this doesn't work.

I tried `condition = "input.p_id.indexOf(d1)!=-1"` but it also doesn't work.

Anyone can suggest what is the right `js` syntax for what I am trying to achieve? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want in a simpler fashion, without using the `conditionalPanels.` We could generate the `selectInput` once, and then update it with `updateSelectInput` whenever the other `input` changes. Here is a working example:

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  selectInput('maxdays','Max number of days:', c(1,2,3)),
  selectInput('days','Days:',c(1))
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session,'days',choices=seq(1,input$maxdays))
  })
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server))
```

---

An alternative solution would be to use `renderUI` to re-render your `selectInput` whenever the first `selectInput` changes:

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  selectInput('maxdays','Max number of days:', c(1,2,3)),
  uiOutput('uiDays')
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$uiDays <- renderUI({
    selectInput('days','Days:', choices=seq(1,input$maxdays))
  })

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, @Florian. This helped me understand the problem but it doesn't directly solve it. In my example, I had to create a variable `maxdays` based on the input `p_id` but the concept is very similar. I will add the solution as an answer but I will accept yours. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Florian. I modified his answer and here is a possible way of achieving the desired behavior:

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  selectInput('p_id','ID:', c(111,222,333)),
  uiOutput('uiID')
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  maxdays <- reactive({
    if(input$p_id %in% c(111)){
      x = 1
    }else{
      if(input$p_id %in% c(222)){
        x = 2
      }else
        x = 3 
    }
    return(x)
  })


  output$uiID <- renderUI({
    selectInput('days','Days:', choices=seq(1,maxdays()))
  })


}

runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server))
```

In my app the list `c(111,222,333)` and the corresponding lists are variables in the dataset and are defined at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Hi @M_M, nice solution, glad I could point you in the right direction ;)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to use `conditionalPanel`, the condition is written in Javascript so you can use the `includes()` method.

Benefit IMO is it is contained in a single `modalDialog`.

```
library(shiny)

##conditionally show another part of modal on checkbox
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('go', "Go!")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    shiny::showModal(
      modalDialog(title = "Look at this modal!",
        shiny::checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "cond_inp",
                            label = "Select bits of modal to see:",
                            choices = c("One", "Two", "Three")),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.cond_inp.includes('One')",
          textInput("one", "Part one:")
        ),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.cond_inp.includes('Two')",
          textInput("two", "Part two:")
        ),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.cond_inp.includes('Three')",
          textInput("three", "Part three:")
        ),
        easyClose = FALSE,
        footer = tagList(
          actionButton(inputId = "go_next", label = "Confirm"),
          modalButton("Cancel")
        )
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```