# R Shiny - conditionnal panel based on list

Tags: r, shiny

Yes, there are many questions phrased very similary, for instance

[r shiny - conditionalPanel with condition: check item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760041/r-shiny-conditionalpanel-with-condition-check-item-in-list) or [Multiple conditions in condition panel R shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52104617/multiple-conditions-in-condition-panel-r-shiny)

None, however, seems to sort the problem - that in addition seems to be one of js syntax more than R proper.

Consider the following MRE:

```
library(shiny)

collective <- c("happiness","love","peace","time","foo","bar")
numerable <- c("apple","orange","banana","quux","baz","bob")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectInput("choice","choose one",choices=c(collective,numerable)),
  
    conditionalPanel(
    condition = TRUE, ## This is the condition I need to write !
    numericInput("number",
                "How many?",
                value=3)
  ),
  
  
  textOutput("result")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$result <- renderText({
    
    if(is.null(input$number)){
      paste("You want some", input$choice)
    }else{
      paste("you want",input$number,input$choice)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here I want to show the number box only if the user choices something that can be counted.

In plain R, I would write my condition as
`if(input$choice %in% numerable)` ... etc.

However the condition must be written in js at that point.

The question is therefore, **how do I translate this R statement into a js condition that will work in this context** ?

Similar questions got the following answers, or perhaps workarounds:

**1) Use a `renderUI` instead, which can be coded in R like so:**

```
    output$numberUI <- renderUI({
        if( input$choice %in% numerable) {
            # pass
        }else{
              numericInput("number",
              "How many?",
              value=3)
            }
    })
```

and replace the conditional panel by `uiOutput("numberUI")`. This works indeed, in actual fact this is what I'm doing now in my "real" app, but I find the resulting code to be less readable with the UI definition scattered between UI and server.

**2) Explicitly list all the possible cases** with
`condition = "input.choice == 'apple' || input.choice =='orange' || input.choice == 'banana' " ...` etc., which is obviously clumsy and error prone (and in addition will not work if the list of `numerable` is data-driven, in my case it is in the real app based on `names(the_data)` ).

I'm pretty sure that js has an operator equivalent to R's %in% so the question boils down to how do I translate this R statement: `input$choice %in% numerable` to js ? The obvious `"input.choice in numerable"` does not work, presumably because I first need to convert `numerable` to a js object ?

**EDIT:** based on Stéphane Laurent's below. I realized that of course **condition is a string**, so nothing stops me from **creating the condition string dynamically**. And so:

```
condition = paste('[',paste(paste('"',numerable,'"',sep=''),collapse=','),'].includes(input.choice)',sep='')
```

... if somewhat unreadable (it can be prettified with pipes, `glue` etc) does the job.

Comment: Perhaps `wrap` with `any`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
condition = '["apple","orange","banana","quux","baz","bob"].includes(input.choice)'
```

or

```
condition = '["apple","orange","banana","quux","baz","bob"].indexOf(input.choice) > -1'
```

Comment: Good hint, though not the full solution. I edited my question to add a third possibility building on your suggestion.

Comment: @jfmoyen You can use **jsonlite** to create the JavaScript string from the R list.

Comment: I never touched it. If you know how to do it, Im glad to learn !